# Workflow: how to UNSET (or set to NULL) a date/time type value in a custom column?

Tags: workflow, column

Trying to build a workflow that clears a date column when the task "Completed" box is unchecked.

Have tried several different approaches but have not gotten anything to work.  The workflow completes after the "Completed" box is unchecked but the date is not cleared from the column.

There is no option to select a NULL value, have tried setting an "empty" calendar date but that just defaults to the default date value (undesired) but even then the date is still not cleared.

Thoughts/ideas EXTREMELY WELCOME!

Thank you!

Comment: I think that the problem is that a date columns is really never "empty" in SharePoint. Instead it is set to something like 1/1/0001". One solution could be to have an additional date field that's hidden and empty. When you wanna clear the value in your date column, set it to the hidden empty date columns value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Solution 1:
```

It cant be done. Better off using a text column and ensure that its populated by well coded actions (meaning only valid dates with proper formats gets saved).

And since its a text column, you can always clear it.

```
Solution 2:
```

Default it to 1/1/0001 (if its the default). Then modify your code/workflow/view to filter rows based on the column value != 1/1/0001

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you could create an empty/blank variable (of type Date-Time) and then set the column value to equal your variable.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you.  I tried to do this but it got populated with the default date value 1/1/0001.